# Error in Jena code: Content not allowed in Prolog

Tags: java, jena

I have the following error: Content not allowed in Prolog** I have two methos, one called from main and another from button event handler. One method read the rdf file and another create individual of Student class based on name entered by users in a text field.

What is the expected error.
   My code is:

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.Individual;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import static java.io.FileDescriptor.in;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();    

    public static void readOntology(String file,OntModel model)

     InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(file);

if (in ==null) {
throw new IllegalArgumentException( "File: " + file + " not found");
}
            model.read(in,"");
```

Another method called from Button handler method()

```
 private static void read1(String str,OntModel model)
    {          
        String ns="http://www.semanticweb.org/untitled-ontology-0012/";
     OntClass user = model.createClass(ns + "User");

     OntClass user1 = model.getOntClass(ns + "User");
    Individual janeSmith = user1.createIndividual(ns + str);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, janeSmith.toString());

        try {
           String file="F://student.owl";           

        FileWriter out=new FileWriter(file);                

        } catch (IOException ex) {                Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }           

     private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

OntModel model=ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
        String str=jTextField2.getText();

      read1(str, model);
}
```

And finally main()

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {      

        OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
        // read camera ontology
                String file="F://student.owl";
        readOntology(file , model );
```

Comment: What does all this Java code and Jena have to do with Prolog?

Comment: @lurker: The code somehow has a prolog, a the question suggests.

Comment: If the first block of code is your class, you're missing brackets for your method declaration.

Comment: "Prolog" here is "XML Prolog"

Comment: Duplicate from the jena users mailing list.

Comment: I have added/edited this code to write it to a file, but it removed every thing from my file. FileOutputStream f1=new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        //RDFWriter d = model.getWriter("RDF/XML-ABBREV");
      model.write(f1,"RDF/XML-ABBREV");
 }catch(Exception e) {}